# How can I stop alarms triggering inside max pyramid argument?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have some PineScript codes executin, the alarms are sent out to my MT4 account to execute trades, alarms should only go off when a trade gets executed in tradingview. The problem is that they keep getting executed even though max pyramid has been reached and I have that condition set.
Any idea on how to stop this from happening? here's some of the code:

```
//Strategy
maxPyramid = input.int(title="Max Pyramiding", defval=3)
Long = high > h1[1] and close > regime and rangehl > 4 and strategy.opentrades <= maxPyramid

Short = close < l1[1] and rangehl > 5 and strategy.opentrades <= maxPyramid

m_check_l = close > mid[1] and close[5] > mid[5] and close[6] > mid[6]



if Long and m_check_l and time > startDate and time < endDate
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long)
    

if ta.crossunder(close, mid) 
    strategy.close('Long')
    alert(message = "close UKSUGAR long", freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)

if Short and time > startDate and time < endDate
    strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short)
    
    
if ta.crossover(close, mid)
    strategy.close('Short')
    alert(message = "close UKSUGAR short", freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)

//Alerts
if Long and strategy.opentrades <= maxPyramid
    alert(message = "buy UKSUGAR q=1", freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    
if Short and strategy.opentrades <= maxPyramid
    alert(message = "sell UKSUGAR q=1", freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `alert_message` parameter of `strategy.x` calls.

```
if ta.crossunder(close, mid) 
    strategy.close('Long')
    alert(message = "close UKSUGAR long", freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

You have an `alert()` call inside an if block. What's gonna happen is, if that if condition is true, it will execute that `strategy.close()` and `alert()` call. Those are two different calls. `strategy()` calls will depend on your strategy settings but the `alert()` call will be executed anyway.

```
if ta.crossunder(close, mid) 
    strategy.close('Long', alert_message="close UKSUGAR long")
```

If you use the `alert_message` parameter, alert message will be triggered if that strategy call is executed.